# Which Programming Language is more supportive to start with Selenium?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium2, languages

I am looking to start with selenium, so please suggest me which language is good for automation testing?

Comment: What do you mean by supportative?

Comment: I thing if we are able to quantify supportativeness, e.g. by the response time a community for a given language binding has, theb there is no reason to close this question as opinion based.

Comment: @dzieciou didn't quite get your point. Would you explain?

Comment: @TESTasy do you think this question should be closed? If so, then why?

Comment: @dzieciou,TESTasy I think It was a Opinion based question & it has no limit to answer.
So this one should be closed.

Comment: I believe it depends on an individual as to what programming language they would prefer. We can only guess that by supportive S P is talking about response time a community for a given binding has. But we can't be sure. So I'm not sure what exactly s/he is actually asking or talking about. As far as the choice of programming language to start with Selenium depends on an individual's familiarity and ease with one and hence is opinion based!

Comment: absolutely right, opinion based questions should be closed.

Answer (score 4):

> Selenium supports various programming languages like **Java, Perl, Python, Ruby, C#(.Net)** etc.

So it's mainly up to you. You should choose the language itself, and not the bindings.
If you were to force me to name the language you should use- **JAVA**.
I would have to give you the famous then-
**Java** is a my first choice to start with Selenium(even if it is a bit more difficult)

- Learning Java is useful for learning other non-functional testing types like performance testing (JMETER allows using Java for bean shell scripts) and API testing (SOAP UI allows using Groovy, a flavor of Java, for assertions).
- java seems to be still the most popular language on the job market.
- Some people says that Ruby and Python are easier to learn and suggest to learn Java later.

But if you should learn it anyways, Since Selenium itself is developed in Java so why not start with it?

> **Java holds an advantage because it is widely used, and easily finding examples on Google to help you out when you’re stuck is a plus.**

*Finally its upto you, All languages have their pros and cons. One is not better or worse than any other. It really does depend on your situation and what you are trying to accomplish.*

Comment: Why not in Java? You just said it: because Python is **substantially** easier for beginner. Just one look at input/output declaration should be enough for a beginner to switch from Java to Python. Do you know Python?

Comment: @Peter Masiar, I think you have not read my answer carefully. I have already selected Java as a first option for beginners. I said- Some people says that Ruby and Python are easier to learn and suggest to learn Java later. If Selenium itself is developed in Java so why not start with JAVA?

Comment: I did read what you wrote, that's why commented. I also have experience teaching beginners both Python and Java (in that order), so I know **exactly** how much more is Java for beginners. From your answer I assume you do not know Python much, am I right?

Comment: @PeterMasiar- I think its your misunderstanding. Thanks anyway's & sorry for all. Yes I dont know very well about Python. but it doesn't mean I'm arguing with any programming language. finally It's up to the beginners capacity & his interest. 
Thanks anyway's. Don't mind If I said anything in above comment.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium has bindings for the most common languages (see http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) so use the one either you know best, and/or the one your development team uses for easier integration in the development cycle and common use of tools.

Comment: As a rule of thumb I use the development language of the SUT. It just works best for everyone.